# How do I loop through dataframe having TimeStamp index with different dates being one loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, datetime, timestamp

My dataframe has index timestamp. I want to divide my dataframe based on days. So what I'm doing

```
df['index_day'] = df.index.floor('d')
for day, i in df.groupby('index_day'):
```

The loop works fine.

However, i want to access the night time similarly since date changes at 00:00. I want the whole night to be one loop, let's say from `18:00 till 6:00 = one loop` instead of `00:00 till 00:00 of next date = one loop`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer. First we'll have to create a range in timestamp index in which we want to work. with 
`rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-10', periods=35, freq='H')`
Than slice the dataframe the one with data containing that durations only
`df = df.between_time('18:00:01', '6:00')`

And for the looping part, you can, you can loop though with your data with

```
for i, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='12H', base=6, closed='right')):
    if not g.empty:
        *start working on the loop*
```